# Ajax Javascript doesn't change the style without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I have to create a web page that allows recipients to reserve the available meals or remove them (if they were previously reserved), also if the meal is reserved, then its style must change.

but i keep facing this problem where **the style of (the meal's name) doesn't change unless I refresh the page**. also, when i click reserve, the database gets updated and the remove buttons shows up, but **it gets disabled and i cant click it any more unless i refresh the page.**

this is Ajax Javascript part of the recipient Home page :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" > </script>
  <script>
      
      $(document).ready(function(){

           //when remove button is clicked 
          $(".rmvJQ").click(function(){
           
             var classIdValue =  this.value;
             var toResvBtn = "#" + classIdValue +"toResvBtn";
             var ToRmv = "#" + classIdValue +"ToRmv";
                    //  var styleM = "#" + classIdValue +"toStyle";

             
             
          $.get("rmov.php", {classID : classIdValue},
          function(response){
              var opeartion = "success";
              if(response == opeartion){
                  alert("The remove operation was failed");
              }else{
                 // alert(classIdValue); 
             }
             
           $("#RemovedSt").css("background-color");
           $(toResvBtn).html("<button class ='rsvJQ'  value ="+classIdValue+" >Reserve</button>");  
           $(ToRmv).html("");      
          
    });
});
    
       //when reserve button is clicked 
      $(".rsvJQ").click(function(){
            
            var classIdValue =  this.value;
            var toResevededString = "#" +classIdValue + "toResevededString";
            var tormovBtn = "#" + classIdValue + "tormovBtn";
            var ReservedSt = "#" + classIdValue + "ReservedSt";

         $.get("rsv.php", {classID : classIdValue},
          function(response){
               var opeartion = "success";
              if(response == opeartion){
                  alert("The reseve operation was failed");
              }else{
                  alert("The reseve operation was successful!"); 
             }   
             
              $(ReservedSt).css({"background-color": "yellow", "font-size": "200%"});
              $(toResevededString).html("Reserved");
              $(tormovBtn).html("<button class ='rmvJQ' value = '"+classIdValue+"' >Remove</button>");   
    });
   });
  });

        </script>
```

and this is the php/html part of the same page

```
        
<?php
        
        $error= mysqli_connect_errno();
        if($error!=null){
            echo "<p>unable to connect with db</p>";
            exit($output);
        }
        else 
        {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM restaurant";
        $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);


        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
             $restaurantID=$row['id'];
             $sql="SELECT * FROM meal WHERE restaurant_id=".$restaurantID;
             $meals=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
             $check = mysqli_num_rows($meals);
             if($check>0){

        //list of meals for each restaurant
        echo '<table id= "mealsList">';
        echo '<thead>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<caption>".$row['name']."</caption>" ;    
        echo "<tr ><th > Meals </th>"
         . "<th colspan='2' > Status </th>"
         ."<br><br></tr>";

        echo'</thead>';
//each meal 

echo'<tbody>';
                  
           $resv=array(); //reserved meals   
           $remv=array(); //removed meals       
           while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($meals)){
           $sql4="SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE meal_id=".$row['id']." AND recipient_id=".$_SESSION['recipient_id'];
           $res4=mysqli_query($con,$sql4);
           $row4=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res4);
            if($row4){
                 $resv[]=$row;
             }
             else{
               $remv[]=  $row;
             }
           }
             $i=0;
             while($i<count($resv) ){
                 echo '<tr >';
                 echo '<td id="'.$resv[$i]['id'].'ReservedSt" ><a style="background-color:#00ff00" href="MealInfo.php?mealID='.$resv[$i]['id'].'">'.$resv[$i]['name'].''.'</a> </td>';
                 echo '<td id="'.$resv[$i]['id'].'toResvBtn">Reserved</td>';
                 echo '<td id="'.$resv[$i]['id'].'ToRmv"><button class = "rmvJQ" value = "'.$resv[$i]['id'].'" >Remove</button></td>';
                 echo '</tr>';
                 $i++;
              }
               $i=0;
             while($i<count($remv)){
                $checkZero = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT qty FROM meal WHERE id =".$remv[$i]['id']);
                $checkZ=mysqli_fetch_assoc($checkZero);

             if($checkZ['qty']>0){
                 echo '<tr id="RemovedSt" style="background-color:white" >'
                . '<td  ><a href="MealInfo.php?mealID='.$remv[$i]['id'].'">'.$remv[$i]['name'].'</a></td>' //<a href="enroll.php?classID='.$row['id'].'">Enroll</a>
                . '<td id= "'.$remv[$i]['id'].'toResevededString"> <button class = "rsvJQ" value = "'.$remv[$i]['id'].'" >Reseve</button> </td>'
                . '<td id = "'.$remv[$i]['id'].'tormovBtn"></td>'
                . '</tr>';
                 
             }else{
                 
                 echo '<tr>';
                 echo '<th ><a style="color:black;" href="MealInfo.php?mealID='.$remv[$i]['id'].'">'.$remv[$i]['name'].'</a> </th>';
                 echo '<td colspan="2" >  meal is not available   </td >';
                 echo '</tr>';
             }
                 $i++;
             }//end of while loop
             
echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
        }//end of if($check>0)
     }//end of big while
 }//end of big if-else
?>
```

[an image of Recipient Home page with each restaurant and their available meals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7edb.png)

So have anyone faced this problem or know how to solve it please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's a little unclear why you are assigning CSS styling to the element versus assigning / removing specific Class names. This makes changing the Style much easier on you and often faster all together. We also need to view the resulting HTML and not the PHP to be able to properly assist. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You said html/php of same page?, as you are using AJAX its better to have php code in a separate file or even in a single file you need to control the flow of execution.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

Configure PHP to create the following **HTML** structure.

```
<table id="mealsList">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <caption>Vendor Name 1</caption>
    <tr>
      <th>Meals</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="item-1001">
      <td class="mealName">
        <a class="highlight-green" href="MealInfo.php?mealID=1001">Meal Item 1</a>
      </td>
      <td class="mealStatus">Reserved</td>
      <td class="mealOptions">
        <button class="btn btn-remove">Remove</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="item-1002">
      <td class="mealName">
        <a class="highlight-green" href="MealInfo.php?mealID=1002">Meal Item 2</a>
      </td>
      <td class="mealStatus">Reserved</td>
      <td class="mealOptions">
        <button class="btn btn-remove">Remove</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="item-1003">
      <td class="mealName">
        <a class="highlight-green" href="MealInfo.php?mealID=1003">Meal Item 3</a>
      </td>
      <td class="mealStatus">Reserved</td>
      <td class="mealOptions">
        <button class="btn btn-remove">Remove</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can see here, in the HTML Structure, we assign the Item ID to the Row versus each part of the row. This makes it a lot more relative when we need to assign event callbacks later. There is one point of reference.

Then apply the following **CSS**

```
#mealsList {
  width: 340px;
}

.highlight-green {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}

.highlight-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.big {
  font-size: 200%;
}
```

This makes it easier for you to add or remove classes on elements instead of changing the specific styling. This also makes it easier to manage the changes in the future, you just update the CSS and then do not have to adjust your PHP or JS code.

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  function removeItem(id) {
    $.get("rmov.php", {
        classID: id,
        html: "success"
      },
      function(response) {
        if (response == "success") {
          console.log("Remove Successful");
          $("#item-" + id + " .mealName a").removeClass("highlight-green");
          $("#item-" + id + " .mealStatus").html("");
          $("#item-" + id + " .mealOptions .btn").html("Reserve").toggleClass("btn-remove btn-reserve");
        }
      });
  }

  function reserveItem(id) {
    $.get("rsv.php", {
        classID: id,
        html: "success"
      },
      function(response) {
        if (response == "success") {
          console.log("Reserve Successful");
          $("#item-" + id + " .mealName a").addClass("highlight-yellow big");
          $("#item-" + id + " .mealStatus").html("Reserved");
          $("#item-" + id + " .mealOptions .btn").html("Remove").toggleClass("btn-remove btn-reserve");
        }
      });
  }

  $("#mealsList").on("click", ".btn-remove", function(event) {
    removeItem($(this).closest("tr").attr("id").split("-")[1]);
  });

  $("#mealsList").on("click", ".btn-reserve", function(event) {
    reserveItem($(this).closest("tr").attr("id").split("-")[1]);
  });
});
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/wLzakshp/9/

First we want to use jQuery `.on()` to assign the event callbacks in this use case. This is because elements might be added or changed and this type of assignment is good for that.

> **Delegated event handlers** have the advantage that they can process events from *descendant elements* that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated event handlers to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

See More: https://api.jquery.com/on/

I used functions to make it a bit easier to repeat specific actions. The functions accept the ID (from the Row) and send that detail to the proper script. If it is successful, specific changes are made.